# html table with colspan - adjacent cell problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the below table format . I want to implement jquery functionality when the user click on cell of Row1 of this table.

I want to merge or split the cell based on the user action.

Say , the user click on "7-8" then it has to split into two different cells like 7 and 8 with proper data.

Say , the user click on "2" then the nearest left cell has to be get merged and form a cell like "1-2" with proper data. (As given in "7-8").
Same way if he click on "4" then it should create "3-4" with proper data .

Here Row2 and Row5 cells span for 2 columns in case of merge.(Please see the existing table).

I am trying to implement this by changing the colspan values but it is not viable.
Please suggest a cleaner solution.

```html
<table border=1 style="height:200px; border-top:0px;">
    <tbody id="MySettings">
        <tr>
            <td width="15%">Row1</td>
            <td colspan="0" width="10%">1</td>
            <td colspan="0" width="10%">2<button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:-6px; margin-top:-11px;"> </button></td>
            <td colspan="0" width="10%">3</td>
            <td colspan="0" width="10%">4<button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:-6px; margin-top:-11px;"></button></td>
            <td colspan="0" width="10%">5</td>
            <td colspan="0" width="10%">6<button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:-6px; margin-top:-11px;"> </button></td>
            <td colspan="2" width="10%">7 - 8<button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:-6px; margin-top:-11px;"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="MySettings_2">
            <td>Row2</td>
            <td colspan="0"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" value="1" checked="true"></td>
            <td colspan="0"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox2" value="1" checked="true"></td>
            <td colspan="0"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox3" value="1" checked="true"></td>
            <td colspan="0"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox4" value="1" checked="true"></td>
            <td colspan="0"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox5" value="1" checked="true"></td>
            <td colspan="0"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox6" value="1" checked="true"></td>
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox7_8" value="1" checked="true"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row3">
            <td>Row3</td>
            <td>88.98</td>
            <td>33.98</td>
            <td>43.34</td>
            <td>123.98</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>65.43</td>
            <td>33.19</td>
            <td>27.8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row4">
            <td>Row4</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>340</td>
            <td>555.8</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row5">
            <td>Row5</td>
            <td colspan="0">7</td>
            <td colspan="0">3</td>
            <td colspan="0">6</td>
            <td colspan="0">0</td>
            <td colspan="0">0</td>
            <td colspan="0"> 4</td>
            <td colspan="2">10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[JSfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/raz77c61/1/)

```
$("#MySettings tr:first-child .col2").click(function() {
  if($(this).attr("colspan") == "0") {
  $(this).attr("colspan", "2");
  $(this).prev().css("display","none");
  $(this).text("1-2");
}
else {
  $(this).attr("colspan", "0");
  $(this).text("2");
  $(this).prev().css("display","table-cell");
}
});
```

Hope above Link help you. :)